# iOSで実行した場合、three.jsのライトの数に制限はあるのでしょうか。

Tags: ios, three.js

three.jsで遠隔光源、スポットライト、点光源など複数のライトをシーンに追加してシャドーマップをオンにすると図形が表示されません。

ライトの点灯の有無にかかわらず、シーンに5～7個のライトを追加するとこの現象は発生します。

WebGLRendererでmaxLights: 16としてみましたが状況は変わりませんでした。

webglはライトの制限数が8個までと聞きましたが、Windows、Androidでは問題有りません。iOSだけでの現象となっています。iOSの不具合との認識で良いでしょうか。サンプルではAmbientLightを入れて8個なのでギリギリ制限には引っかからないと思うのですが。

Windows,androidでは正常に表示されます。
iOSでは制限があるのでしょうか。

確認したデバイスはiPhone 5s、iPad Proの二つで確認しています。

解決策をご存知のかた、よろしくお願いいたします。

記入がおそくなり申し訳ございません。
下記にサンプルソースを添付します。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - PointLight ShadowMap </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - PointLight ShadowMap by <a href="https://github.com/mkkellogg">mkkellogg</a>
        </div>

        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var camera, scene, renderer, stats;
            var pointLight, pointLight2;
            var pointLight3, pointLight4, pointLight5, pointLight6, pointLight7;

            var torusKnot;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 10, 40 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222233 ) );

                // Lights

                function createLight( color ) {

                    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( color, 1, 30 );
                    pointLight.castShadow = true;
                    pointLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
                    pointLight.shadow.camera.far = 30;
                    // pointLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
                    pointLight.shadow.bias = 0.01;

                    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.3, 12, 6 );
                    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: color } );
                    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    pointLight.add( sphere );

                    return pointLight

                }

                pointLight = createLight( 0xffffff );
                scene.add( pointLight );

                pointLight2 = createLight( 0xff0000 );
                scene.add( pointLight2 );

                pointLight3 = createLight( 0x00008b );
                pointLight3.position.set(10,2,0);
                scene.add( pointLight3 );

                pointLight4 = createLight( 0x00ff7f );
                pointLight4.position.set(0,20,10);
                scene.add( pointLight4 );

                pointLight5 = createLight( 0xff7f50 );
                pointLight5.position.set(20,20,20);
                scene.add( pointLight5 );

                pointLight6 = createLight( 0x32CD32 );
                pointLight6.position.set(0,20,-20);
                scene.add( pointLight6 );

                pointLight7 = createLight( 0x32CD32 );
                pointLight7.position.set(10,0,-10);
                scene.add( pointLight7 );


                var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry( 14, 1, 150, 20 );
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    color: 0xff0000,
                    shininess: 100,
                    specular: 0x222222
                } );
                torusKnot = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                torusKnot.position.set( 0, 5, 0 );
                torusKnot.castShadow = true;
                torusKnot.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( torusKnot );

                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    color: 0xa0adaf,
                    shininess: 10,
                    specular: 0x111111,
                    side: THREE.BackSide
                } )
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                mesh.position.y = 10;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.BasicShadowMap;
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                var time = performance.now() * 0.001;

                pointLight.position.x = Math.sin( time ) * 9;
                pointLight.position.y = Math.sin( time * 1.1 ) * 9 + 5;
                pointLight.position.z = Math.sin( time * 1.2 ) * 9;

                time += 10000;

                pointLight2.position.x = Math.sin( time ) * 9;
                pointLight2.position.y = Math.sin( time * 1.1 ) * 9 + 5;
                pointLight2.position.z = Math.sin( time * 1.2 ) * 9;

                torusKnot.rotation.y = time * 0.1;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

                stats.update();

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 状況(Windows,androidでは正常に表示、iOSでは図形が表示されない)を再現できるようなソースコードはご呈示いただけるでしょうか。ご自身の質問は「編集」可能なはずですので、是非ソースコードをご質問内容に追記してください。容易に再現可能なソースコードが記載された質問は、より多くの人に解決方法を考えてもらえるようになります。

Comment: 最新のthree.js r86でも状況は変わりません。表示されないと言う表現が悪いのかもしれませんが、途中までしか描画がされない状況です。同じような状況の方、いらっしゃいませんか？

Answer (score 3):

PC、Androidでも8〜15個程光源を入れると同じ現象がでました。
ハードウエアリソース(主にGPU)またはOSの制限のようです。
iOSの場合、制約がきついようです。